# Editing feed for thumbnails and link

Tags: feed

I want to display post thumbnails and hyperlinks in post on my feed page. I know in templates you can copy page template and modify it, but here i am dealing with wp-includes/feed.php or wp-includes/feed-rss . I have two question

1. what can i do get to get thumbnails of post and links of post?
2. If i edit the feed template, tomorrow when wordpress updates, it will remove my custom code, how can i make it like a child-template, so my code doesn't get disturbed, when new updates come.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to edit WordPress core files and don't do this, when hooks are available to modify use `the_excerpt_rss` and `the_content_feed` filter to add thumbnails or your custom links in feed.

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );

function insert_thumbnail_into_feed() {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        // replace thumbnail with yours
        $content = '<p>' .get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) .'</p>';
    }

    // get post content and replace feed content with
    // you can also limit/filter the content to exclude shortcodes and html code etc.
    $content .= '<p>' .get_the_content() .'</p>';

    return $content;
}
```

EDIT: place this code in your theme's functions.php

Comment: By hyperlink i meant, that any link in the post, comes as a hyperlink in rss too.Will it return the way i described above?

Comment: oh i see, then you need to replace feed content with yours. wait i am going to edit my answer.

Comment: Also i see, this will show up in rss2 or atom? how do i make the feed by default to the one which shows that thumbnails, and hyperlink

Comment: any help. still waiting for the answer to be updated.

Comment: @Nofel i have updated answer about 9 hours ago, but was forget to notify you about changes, please copy and paste code into your functions.php

Comment: thank you! but how do i know which code make hyperlink in excerpt? The above said code works in rss2 but by default the site loads simple rss.how can i change it to default to be rss2